# Sound Logos: What's your favourite? 

Tags: sound-logos, favourite

Hi All,

I've been gathering examples of famous and nice sound logo designs.
Unfortunately most 'sound logos' are actually 'music logos' :(

Here are some nice examples:

Classic: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVCxJ1aT24A

Musical: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0EB_vl4rik
         http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8VFwZkp384

Technology: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vccECcGRtSE

What are your favourites?

Oh and yes I know about the wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_branding

Comment: WOW That Hamburg City Orchestra one is brilliant!!

Comment: Yeah I love it! Simple idea, executed brilliantly!

Answer (score 1):

And, of course, there is the the Intel signature audio ID (hey, they used to call it the Intel Bong for years, give 'em a break :-p). It's been [executed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzrEqQLuMow) in [many](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/my-intel-edge/sxsw-artists-rock-the-intel-bong.html) [ways](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dt9maknsGJ0) and has been called the 2nd most "addictive" sound in the USA [by one survey](http://www.michaelleander.me/blog/the-10-most-recognizable-sounds-in-the-world-usa/). The [story of its composition](http://musicthing.blogspot.com/2005/05/tiny-music-makers-pt-1-intel-inside.html) by Walter Werzowa is pretty interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The original PlayStation boot screen.

THX aka "Deep Note".

There could be more had I heard more, but these are the ones that have struck me as sounding particularly good/interesting/distinctive.

Comment: i like the playstation logo! dark and light at the same time. reminds me of blade runner a bit, all it needs is a slow down bending sawtooth :)

Answer (score 0):

I really like the Citroen sonic logo. They've been using it for quite a few years now and I really associate the sound effect with the Citoren brand.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=wpfkI5FK_NY#t=26s

Comment: nice one, what do you think makes it good, the vocals or the contrast with the 'sparky'beat?


Comment: They don't always use the V.O. so I'd say the real sonic logo is the glitchy sfx. It's a sound that I that I find to be really well designed - rhythmically it's very catchy but the glitchy fx that is used makes it more complex than a simple beat pattern. 

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=qeSnUzHNTA8

I really like this one for sound and visuals.. Brilliant

Comment: hi, did post the correct link? this looks like a commercial for mercedes instead of a sound logo.. well executed btw, although i didn't like the VO. 

Answer (score 0):

The current HBO is great:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmIvu1yg3bU

but the classic is amazing (epic and musical, but brings back so many memories):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1NKoMNy5bY

Pixar:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sI8T_u-GUyU

I am sure there are many more!!

Answer (score 0):

I love this for the sheer simplicity, its the old SEGA one:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0y6hIABR-nU

Answer (score 0):

I really like the Intel logo and the Boot-up logo for Game Cube.